# How do I package this vbscript as a msi for Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, vbscript, msi

I had a developer that is no longer with us create an msi to do this for me, but the package is outdated now and we need to deploy new files.

Basically I need to do the following:

1. Take the code at the bottom of this question and deploy it to all users as a software install package in Group Policy.  I don't want to use a computer startup script because I don't want this to run at every login...just once to install and be done.

How can I take the below and turn it into an msi for deployment through GPO?

```
    @echo off

copy "\\tuldc01\EOneActiveXapplets\ActiveX898\jdeexpimpU\jdeexpimp.inf" "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" /Y
copy "\\tuldc01\EOneActiveXapplets\ActiveX898\jdeexpimpU\jdeexpimpU.ocx" "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" /Y
copy "\\tuldc01\EOneActiveXapplets\ActiveX898\jdewebctlsU\jdewebctls.inf" "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" /Y
copy "\\tuldc01\EOneActiveXapplets\ActiveX898\jdewebctlsU\jdewebctlsU.ocx" "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" /Y

regsvr32 "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\jdeexpimpU.ocx" /s
regsvr32 "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\jdewebctlsU.ocx" /s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely the best (and possibly the only) way to achieve your goal:

- First, [turn the VBScript into an .exe file](http://renegadetech.blogspot.com/2006/07/how-to-convert-bat-file-or-vbs-file.html).
- Second, [turn the .exe file into an MSI](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi.htm). (That's probably the best free MSI Making tool out there)
- Third, profit!

Let us know how it works!

Comment: The first step acted like it worked...but The EXE itself won't run, even by itself.  I should mention that I've changed the batch file in the original post since I had syntax errors.

Comment: @TheCleaner Hmmm... That's beginning to be out of my league. I know there are other VBS to EXE tools out there, but most are for-pay. For example: http://www.abyssmedia.com/scriptcryptor/ and http://www.scriptcode.com/ - Then there's this crazy thing for which I have no idea if it really works: http://www.vbs2exe.com/

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at those links and see what I can figure out.  I'll update soon.